# Connect Photos app with Facebook/Flickr

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, facebook, flickr, windows-store-app

I'm trying to use **Windows 8 Photos (Metro App)**, I tried to connect Photos App with my **Flickr** and **Facebook** accounts which both associated with a **Yahoo Mail** account, But it seems it requires a **Hotmail** account associated Flickr and Facebook accounts to connect. Am I missing something here...? or how to connect to Flickr/Facebook account which are associated with non Microsoft mail address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it requires a Microsoft Account. You can [create one](https://signup.live.com), even with non-Microsoft email addresses. I've heard people complain they don't want a Hotmail account, but I've succesfully set up a Microsoft account for my wife with her email address from our internet provider.

In the signup page, don't click 'Or get a new email address', but just enter your Yahoo Mail. This will also be your 'username' (what you use to login to your Microsoft Account):

[image: Signing up for a Microsoft account with a Yahoo email address]

After that, you can [login](https://login.live.com) to your account and link to your Twitter, Flickr, Facebook, etc accounts.